# Why doesn't jQuery().remove() and unbind() work in GreaseMonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to use the `jQuery().remove()` and `jQuery().unbind` methods (and similar functions) in a greaseMonkey script but it's not working. The same exact calls work in fireBug though. I'm guessing that it has something to do with GM sandboxing and the fact that the scope is completely off.

I did try to use `unsafeWindow.jQuery` and even declared `window = unsafeWindow` yet it didn't help.

All the other jQuery stuff (eg `clone` `append` )is working perfect.

Anyone have any thoughts or suggestions about this?

EDIT: code:

```
(function($) {
    var changeURLs = function() {
        var window = unsafeWindow;
            $('.link-results li').each(function() {
                var $a = $(this).find('a'), directUrl;
                if ($a.hasClass('redirect')) return;
                $a.unbind('click'); //!! Not working
                if (/sidereel\.com/.test($a[1].href)) { // Megavideo like link
                    $.get($a[1].href, function(data) {
                        directUrl = $(data).find('.play-link')[0].innerHTML;
                        $a[1].href = $a[2].href = directUrl;
                        $a.each(function() {
                            unsafeWindow.console.log( $(this).remove() ); //!! Not working
                        });
                    });
                } else { // Sponsered link
                    $a[2].href = $a[1].href;
                }
                $a.addClass('redirect');
            });
        },
        $thickBox = $('.ui-dialog-content');
    if ($thickBox.length) $thickBox.dialog('close')

    changeURLs();
    jQuery('.link-results-container').bind('DOMNodeInserted', changeURLs);
})(unsafeWindow.jQuery);
```

Comment: @motionman95: How about all of it?

Answer (score -1):

Heres another one to load up the JQuery from google if it is not already present on the page:
http://joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey/